# use variable in mqsql query statement

Tags: mysql

i want to remove hard coded Item_code and put a $whereis variable. but what is the correct syntax to do that?

```
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM `stock`
    WHERE Item_code = '{$testingone}' AND size='{$sizurl}'
    ";
```

Comment: Everybody loves SQL injection!

Comment: @tc. If `$testingone` and `$sizurl` are not user-supplied, then there is no vulnerability.

Comment: To clarify tc's point, Yasitha: a site that incorporates code like yours is potentially vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, if user data can ever make its way into either of those two variables. It's a serious problem. There are lots of questions on this site discussing ways of avoiding this problem. [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySqli*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thank you very much guys. you save me... 
i always used mysql_real_escape_string
              preg_match
so is it still vulnerable to do this ?

Comment: @cdhowie: It still violates the principle of preserving semantics (it does not need to be user-supplied to contain a '), and I strongly suspect that "Item_code" is user-supplied. Besides, prepared statements are often significantly more efficient.

Comment: @tc. Of course. I'm not saying that it's a good idea, only that if the variables don't come from user input, it's not a critical security problem that needs to be addressed immediately.

Comment: Wow Great Advices... Thnak you all very much... i will never do that mistake again...
in this case item_code is user supplied thing,. but i'm making this web based application not for use in internet. but for use in a small pharmacy so the risk is much lower. 
any way your advices are  very much valuable for me ... Thank you all again..

Comment: @cdhowie: If not, then it is probably a critical security problem that will manifest itself a few months later when your "test server" becomes the production server without sufficient code review. Bad practices are always bad practices.